# Show that a function is in $H^1(B_1(0))$ with polar coordinates (classical example)

Tags: functional-analysis, examples-counterexamples, lp-spaces, sobolev-spaces

One of the common examples to show that $H^1(\Omega)$ functions are not continuous in an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, $n>1$ is the following.

> Let $\Omega =B_1(0)$ and $$f(x,y)=|\log(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}})|^k$$
> for $k \in (0, \frac{1}{2})$.
> Then $f \in H^1$, but it's not continuous.

I can't prove that the partial are in $L^2$. I'll show here what I tried so far.

First of all, since I am in $B_1(0)$, then $x^2+y^2<1 \Longrightarrow \sqrt{x^2+y^2} <1 \Longrightarrow \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}>1$, hence the argument of $\log$ is greater than $1$ and then the logarithm is positive on the unit ball, so I can remove the absolute value.

Then I compute the partial: $$\partial_x f(x,y)= \frac{k x \log \Bigl(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\Bigr)^{k-1}}{x^2+y^2}$$

Using polar coordinates: $$\int_0^{2 \pi} \int_0^1 \frac{k^2 r^2 \cos(\theta)^2 \log(\frac{1}{r})^{2(k-1)}}{r^4} r dr d \theta = \int_0^{2\pi} \cos(\theta)^2 \int_0^1 k^2 \frac{\log(1/r)^{2(k-1)}}{r}dr$$

but I don't know how to handle the latter integrals. The first one is not $0$ of course, but I don't know if the other one is convergent or not. What should I do here?